# Understanding Gauss-Jordan elimination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have a following system:

$$x_1 + x_2 - x_3 = 5$$
$$2x_1 + 2x_2 - 4x_3 = 6$$
$$x_1 + x_2 - 2x_3 = 3$$

I dont understand how to solve this system using Gauss-Jordan elimination. I was told it I had to have a final result of something like this:

let $x$ represents any other number

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&x&x&x&x\\0&1&x&x&x\\0&0&1&x&x\end{bmatrix}$$

but I had seen some solutions like this:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&x&x&x&x\\0&0&1&x&x\\0&0&0&1&x\end{bmatrix}$$

If someone can explain clearly how I can go about solving this, that would be great!

I have done some steps at the moment but had stopped because I was not sure. This is what I have before me:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&-1&5\\0&0&1&2\\0&0&-1&-2\end{bmatrix}$$

Thanks!

Comment: Notice that the last row is twice the second row, so RREF will have a row of zeros. This means you just have to do GE on the first two rows, which reduces your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- $R_3 = 2R_3 - R_2$, that is, it is an all zeros row
- Swap $R_1$ with $R_2$
- $R_2 = R_2 - (1/2)R_1$
- $R_2 = R_2/6$

Can you see the final form and tell your solution set from this Gaussian Elimination?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, very good. You can now add the second row to the third giving
$$\pmatrix{1&1&-1&{\it 5} \\
0&0&1&{\it 2} \\
0&0&0&{\it 0}
}$$
Now rewrite it to equations:
$$\begin{align}
x_1+x_2-x_3&=5 \\
x_3 &=2
\end{align}$$
This will give you all the solutions:

> $x_3$ must be $2$, and then by the other equation, 
>   $x_1+x_2=7$ in arbitrary way.

So, say, $x_1\in\Bbb R$ can be arbitrary and then $x_2=7-x_1$.